# Is it possible to put variables inside a GraphQL-tag?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, graphql-tag

Right now I have this tag below. It's static and will always get a comment with the id of 3. Is there a possible way to put a variable inside this graphQL-tag. So I can re-use the graphQL-tag, and just change the variable ID?

```
export const GET_COMMENTS: any = gql`
    {
        comments(id: 3) {
            userId,
            text,
            creationDate,
      }
    }
`;
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: In your code why `query GET_COMMENTS` is not there? You can check my answer below...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yeah, you can pass variables in the **GQL** queries. `$xyz` is kind of notation or variable name to pass variables in **GQL**.

```
export const GET_COMMENTS: any = gql`
    query GET_COMMENTS($id: Int){ // $id is the variable name
        comments(id: $id) {
            userId,
            text,
            creationDate,
      }
    }
`;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found out. That i used some of my queries the wrong way. Implemented your method, and now works :-)

Comment: can someone help me with what is wrong here?

export const getMeSomething = gql`

  query GetSomething(

    $X: ID!
    $Y: ID!
    $Z: ID!
  ) {
    getSomething(
      X: $X
      Y: $Y
    ) {
      Funds(filter: { MyID: { eq: $Z } }) {
        items {
          Amount
          MyID
          
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

Comment: @Rajul What error are you getting?